# Server randomly receiving ctrl-c

Tags: linux, ssh

I have CentOS-server on VirtualBox (Using Vagrant) which is running a very long php-script (It can take up to 5 weeks to fully complete) This script is runned over ssh using cygwin.

The script is running fine, however at some random points the server receives ctrl-C and I don't know where it comes from?

The script is also capable of running with multiple processes using `popen()`

The script is runned through cli on cygwin and can be debugged with PHPstorm 8 EAP.

Here are some technical details about the setup.

Note: All packages are automatically updated through a cronjob.

```
OS:          CentOS 6.5
PHP:         5.4.32 (remi repo)
Apache:      2.2.15 (CentOS repo)
MariaDB:     5.5.39 (MariaDB repo)

Other packages:
PhpMyAdmin    (remi)
Webmin        (Webmin)
OpenSSL       (CentOS)
Bind          (CentOS)
screen        (CentOS)
man           (CentOS)
vim           (CentOS)
git           (CentOS)
zlib-devel    (CentOS)

Other installed RPMs:
libarchive2-2.8.4 (Martin-Juhl)
bsdtar-2.8.4      (Martin-Juhl)

php-plugins (yum installed):
php-common
php-tidy
php-pecl-xdebug
php-mbstring
php-mysqlnd
php-gd
php-mcrypt


Installed group-installs:
Development tools

Host-details:
Windows-8.1
VirtualBox-4.3.12
Vagrant-1.6.5
```

Comment: Do you run your PHP-stuff under GNU screen (I see the package being installed) or is it just a straight SSH connection executing the script?

Comment: @SamiLaine the script is run through ssh. Screen is only used as workaround for apache. it couldn't start at boot because it didn't find its document root on a folder which is mounted after boot.

Comment: so you should start apache later, and make it's initscript depend on the mounted folder.

Comment: Apache does start later. I used the tutorial in the link to get it working. You can see the use of screen there too. It's the only thing it's used for http://razius.com/articles/launching-services-after-vagrant-mount/

Answer (score 0):

By running your script remotely you're adding many layers of complexity, each with its own timeouts.

- Shell idle timeout (TMOUT)
- SSH alive thresholds (ClientAliveCountMax)
- TCP keep-alive limits
- PHP [run time limits](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) (max_execution_time)
- Your client machine may crash, you close the window by accident, etc...

It looks like your workload is primarily batch-based. Please investigate running this script from within the server to avoid external dependencies. If you depend on a mounted folder, do as Dennis suggested, and configure the initscript order/dependency an/or investigate a while for your script to keep checking the folder availability for some time (specify a retry limit so it does not get stuck at boot time).